# Printing tables with zero values in ruby, ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, hash, multidimensional-array, null

I have two-dimensional hash and I want to print in out to simple html table. There was a query like `select section,date,count(*) from table group by section,date` so values for some indexes might not exist.

My ruby code looks like

```
<% sections.each do sec %>
    <tr>
    <% dates.each do date %>
        <% v = 0 %>
        <% v = @rws[sec][date] unless @rws.nil? || @rws[sec].nil? || @rws[sec][date].nil? %>
        <td><%=v%></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Is there a better way to work with multi-dimensional hash without endless checks like `do something with a unless a.nil? || a[b].nil? || a[b][c].nil? || a[b][c][d].nil? ...`?

For example in php I just write:

```
<?php 
    foreach($sections as $sec)
        foreach($dates as $date)
            echo "<td>" . ($rws[$sec][$date]?$rws[$sec][$date]:0) . "</td>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to avoid it. Easiest one I can think of is to replace:

```
    <% v = 0 %>
    <% v = @rws[sec][date] unless @rws.nil? || @rws[sec].nil? || @rws[sec][date].nil? %>
    <td><%=v%></td>
```

with this:

```
    <td><%= (@rws[sec][date] rescue nil) || 0 %></td>
```

Which means: display content of hash. if it throws exception for some reason (like calling  nil[date]), return *nil* instead. (nil || 0) returns zero (which is a default value, I assume).

If the hash contains only numbers, you can also use:

```
    <td><%= (@rws[sec][date] rescue nil).to_i %></td>
```

nil.to_i returns zero. (Watch out though, "some string".to_i returns also zero.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try manually attaching a [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000734) to your `@rws` inside your controller:

```
@rws = pile_of_stuff_that_produces_a_hash
@rws.default_proc = proc do |h,k|
    x = { }
    x.default_proc = @rws.default_proc
    h[k] = x
    x
end
```

Note that the `default_proc` is "inherited" (`x.default_proc = @rws.default_proc`) by the newly created hashes so that you get new hashes all the way down. Then, you could do this:

```
@rws[:where][:is][:pancakes][:house?]
```

And it would work. The downside is that you'd always get an empty hash when you asked for something that wasn't there so you might have to call [`emtpy?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000738) in places where you would normally call [`nil?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001007). So you'd have something like this:

```
<% dates.each do date %>
    <% v = @rws[sec][date] %>
    <td><%= v.is_a?(Hash) && v.empty?? 0 : v %></td>
<% end %>
```

Depending on your specific circumstances, you might be able to trim `v.is_a?(Hash) && v.empty?` down to something a bit nicer; for example, if `@rws` should be numbers all the way down then `v.is_a?(Hash)` would be sufficient.

This `default_proc` approach might be too clever for your specific needs but the general technique is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= @rws && @rws[sec] && @rws[sec][date] %>
```

or with a default value:

```
<%= (@rws && @rws[sec] && @rws[sec][date]) || 0 %>
```

That will return the last value.  Remember that `&&` does short circuit evaluation, and in ruby, only nil and false evaluate to false.

This only works if intermediate values are always nil or a hash... if `@rws[sec] == "foo"`, then it would give an error.

I like the default_proc solution in a few circumstances, especially for deep hashes, but it may be overkill for small usages...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<% sections.each do sec %>
    <tr>
    <% dates.each do date %>
        <td><%= @rws[sec][date] rescue 0 %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```